# Program is creating a duplicate file each time I save a file

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I got a program which asks for the filename and place where to save it with `saveFileDialog1`. Tho it generates an extra file of 0 bytes with exactly the name name. The type of file is `File` and when I open it, it tells me it isnt there. I can see this file in my `Recent files` but cant find it at the place I saved the file. This is my code:

```
private void MaakExcelFile()
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //string zonderspecialchars = RemoveSpecialCharacters(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            copyAlltoClipboard();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlexcel.Visible = true;
            xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add();
            xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range CR = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
            CR.Select();
            xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
            // string zonderspecialchars = RemoveSpecialCharacters(filenaam);
            try
            {
                xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"" + saveFileDialog1.FileName, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { throw e; }
        }
    }
```

Anyone any idea why this happens?
This is how my recent files looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA4Mf.jpg

Comment: Are you perhaps also creating/saving the file inside the `MaakExcelFile()` function?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes thats is where im saving it

Comment: At the first line in my code, I only want to get the path and filename. So I can declare this later in the xlWorkBook.SaveAs

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I moved everything to the `MaakExcelFile()` and I still get the same problem

Comment: You are showing us some code that will not do what you describe. You need to show us the rest of your code as that is where the issue lies

Comment: @Milney okay, I updated the code

Comment: You do know that catching an exception and rethrowing it like you've done is not only pointless, but actively harmful because it destroys critical information about the exception, right? Don't do nonsense like this. If you aren't going to handle an exception, then don't catch it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be happening in MakeExcelFile(); since xlWorkBook.SaveAs will only save the workbook and does not create any additional files.

Edit: try adding workbook.close(). xlapp.Close() after saveas. You may just be keeping that workbook open...

Edit2: Remove your SaveFileDialog and hardcode a path to save the excel file. See if this only saves one file.

Edit3: Hmm.. should do the same thing this way but something is running twice. Either embed the saveasdialog in your try{} block and only saveas with it or switch to a folderbrowserdialog and name the file in the code.

Comment: I changed the code, and the same is still happening

Comment: Yup, then it only saves one file